# cannot reference a dll file in another dll file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am a beginner, I am making a simple calculator using notepad. it has 3 files.
1. first file has some functions like addition, subtraction etc. compiled as dll file.

2. second file also has functions like menu, addition, subtraction etc.this file is also compiled as library file and reference of first file is added in it.

Now when i try to add reference of 1st file in the 2nd file i get an error.

> error cs0143: the type "Calculator"(the first file) has no
>   constructors defined.

How do I remove this error?

**Calculator.cs**

```
using System;
public class Calculator 
{   
    public double Addition(double x, double y)
    {
        return x+y;
    }      
    public double Subtraction(double x, double y)
    {
        return x-y;
    }
    public double Multiplication(double x, double y)
    {
        return x*y;
    }
    public double Division(double x, double y)
    {
        return x/y;
    }
    public double Mod(double x, double y)
    {
        return x%y;
    }
}
```

**CalculatorUI.cs**

```
using System;
public class CalculatorUI
{
    Calculator a=new Calculator();
    public void Menu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1: Addition");
        Console.WriteLine("2: Subtraction");
        Console.WriteLine("3: Multiplication");
        Console.WriteLine("4: Division");
        Console.WriteLine("5: Mod");
        Console.WriteLine("6: Square Root");
        Console.WriteLine("7: Exit");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . . ");
    }   

    private void Addition(string[] args)
    {   
        Console.WriteLine("Enter First Value : ");
        double num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Second Value : ");
        double num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        double ans=a.Addition(num1,num2);
        Console.WriteLine("The Answer is ---> "+ans);
    }

    private void Subtraction(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter First Value : ");
        double num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Second Value : ");
        double num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        double ans=a.Subtraction(num1,num2);
        Console.WriteLine("The Answer is ---> "+ans);
    }
    private void Multiplication(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter First Value : ");
        double num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Second Value : ");
        double num2= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        double ans=a.Multiplication(num1,num2);
        Console.WriteLine("The Answer is ---> "+ans);
    }

    private void Division(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter First Value : ");
        double num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Second Value : ");
        double num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        double ans=a.Division(num1,num2);
        Console.WriteLine("The Answer is ---> "+ans);
    }

    private void Mod(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter First Value : ");
        double num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Second Value : ");
        double num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        double ans=a.Mod(num1,num2);
        Console.WriteLine("The Answer is ---> "+ans);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the other files

Comment: Any reason you're using Notepad?

Comment: @ehh i have updated my complete code

Comment: @Nasreddine I am a beginner, our instructor wants us to code in notepad.

Comment: @salman Honestly, your instructor is crazy (at least)

Comment: @salman Please tell him what's the value of not using Visual Studio? I'm thinking about a person who thinks that focusing on compilation steps turns you into a better programmer :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer i know sir, but they have left us with no choice :( , any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe the instructor is only doing this so they can feel the pain of doing all the steps manually, and then he will introduce working with an IDE in the next few classes.

Comment: Well you don't have a constructor in the Calculator class. Add one and your worries should disappear :)

Comment: @LucMorin yes we will soon start working in visual studio, may be he wants us to know the worth of an IDE :-/

Comment: @KevinAvignon i've tried making one but it still gives the same error

Comment: @KevinAvignon no need to add contructor if there is no params, the default will be called

Comment: You shouldn't be getting this error, could it be you're compiling the wrong file? Perhaps an older version of your code?

Answer (score -1):

From answer number 3 [in here](http://ianswerlist.com/question/361109/the-type-%E2%80%A6-has-no-constructors-defined) it seems you can get this error if you compile for .NET 4 or higher and you are embedding the Interop Types into your managed assembly.
From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264728.aspx) the default setting is false, so check if you are setting this to true on a paramter to the linker.

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.6 and I did not get this type of error when I compiled and ran my solution. 
As for your solution, you could have easily just refer the OP to those two links in comments since you're not bringing any from new but just paraphrasing from the websites you just linked in the answer...

Comment: @kevin, sorry but why should I care about you using 4.6 (as millions of people do)? The OP is developing with notepad therefore manually constructing the compiler and linker command line. My answer suggests that he's using wrong parameters in the linker. As for the links, I just wanted to add the sources I used to provide the answer. Maybe others prefer pretending they know everything without consulting other sources.